# Flutter load image with slider laggy

Tags: flutter

I would like to develop a slider to adjust the brightness of the image instantly.
Just like want Instagram did.

I adopted StreamBuilder to retrieve the image after the brightness is adjusted.
But the image keeps showing image -> black -> image -> black when I am moving the slider.
And the slider is laggy, keep jumping when I move.

Show Image code:

```
child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: _imageRefresher.imageRefreshStream,
    initialData: widget.post.imagesFileList[0].imageFile,
    builder: (context, snap) {
      return PageView.builder(
        controller: PageController(
            initialPage: 0
        ),
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: widget.post.imagesFileList.length,

        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            listIndex = index;
            print(listIndex);
          });
        },
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Hero(
            tag: 'heroFeatured$index',
            child: Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                image: new DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    image: FileImage(snap.data)
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }
)
```

Slider code:

```
child:Slider(
  label: 'Brightness',
  min: -100,
  max: 100,
  value: widget.post.imagesFileList[listIndex].brightness,
  onChanged: (value) {
    print(value);
    setState(() {
      widget.post.imagesFileList[listIndex].brightness = value;
    });
    _imageRefresher.updatePicutre(widget.post.imagesFileList[listIndex].imagePath, value);
    //updatePicutre(widget.post.imagesFileList[listIndex].brightness, value);

  },
),
```

StreamController code:

```
class ImageRefresher {
  StreamController<File> _controller;
  final File imageFile;

  ImageRefresher({this.imageFile}){
    _controller = StreamController();
  }

  Stream<File> get imageRefreshStream => _controller.stream;


  void updatePicutre(String imagePath, double brightness)  async{
    File f = await FlutterNativeImage.adjustBrightness(imagePath, brightness);
    _controller.sink.add(f);
  }

  dispose() {
    _controller.close();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `StreamBuildier` wasn't designed to support image updates. Check out the `Texture` class from Flutter dev it might be better suited for this.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Texture-class.html